# Linear Algebra (Eigenvalue for Polynomials)

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

would like to have a question for eigenvalues for polynomials, please.

This is the question:

> Let $A$ be a 3 x 3 invertible matrix with $λ$ as an eigenvalue of $A$. Show that if $p(x)$ = $2\mathbb{x}$ + $5\mathbb{x}^{-1}$, then $p(λ)$ is an eigenvalue for $p$($A$) = $2A$ + $5A^{-1}$

where I'm currently at:

Looking for the characteristic equation and try to solve the value of $λ$

det$(p(λ)I - p(A))x = 0$

= det$(2λI + 5λ^{-1} I - 2A - 5A^{-1}$) = $0$

when I tried to solve this, I got

$8*det (λI-A) + 125 *det (λ^{-1}I-A^{-1})$ = $0$
, and end up with negative number inside a square root, which is why I don't think I'm doing this correctly.

Any help will be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: if $Av=\lambda v$, then what is $p(A)v$?

Comment: @amd: Hi, thanks for the hints, I got the answer :)